# Spring Integration handling a method issue

Tags: spring-integration

I have an Integration flow that handles a method. 
After pulling a file from FTP server to local, this method reads the csv file ex: foo.csv and creates a new file bar.csv, then bar.csv is ftpd to FTP server again, now the issue is that the method keeps on reading foo.csv and creates a new bar.csv and sends it based on a poller this is done in method fileInboundFlowFromFTPServer, I need to have this process done once and not repeating on the same foo.csv unless it is changed or a new foo.csv is pulled, I have used a JDBC metadatastore with the help of @Gary Russell which is working perfectly as needed but since the handler methods keeps on reading the foo.csv and create a new bar.csv then the date is changed and thus metadatastore is updated and file is being sent again. I'm thinking of a solution to change the name of foo.csv to lets say foo_10012019.csv and send it again to FTP server to a History folder downstream and delete it from local, how can I do this? should I create a new flow for the part of sending foo_10012019.csv only?

here is my integration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
@ComponentScan
public class FTIntegration {

public static final String TIMEZONE_UTC = "UTC";
public static final String TIMESTAMP_FORMAT_OF_FILES = "yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS";
public static final String TEMPORARY_FILE_SUFFIX = ".part";
public static final int POLLER_FIXED_PERIOD_DELAY = 5000;
public static final int MAX_MESSAGES_PER_POLL = 100;


private DataSource dataSource;

//private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FTIntegration.class);
private static final Logger LOG1 = Logger.getLogger(FTIntegration.class);
private static final String CHANNEL_INTERMEDIATE_STAGE = "intermediateChannel";

private static final String OUTBOUND_CHANNEL = "outboundChannel";

/* pulling the server config from postgres DB*/

private final BranchRepository branchRepository;

@Autowired
private CSVToCSVNoQ csvToCSVNoQ;

@Value("${app.temp-dir}")
private String localTempPath;


public FTIntegration(BranchRepository branchRepository) {
    this.branchRepository = branchRepository;
}

@Bean
public Branch myBranch(){
    return new Branch();
}

/**
 * The default poller with 5s, 100 messages, RotatingServerAdvice and transaction.
 *
 * @return default poller.
 */
@Bean(name = PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER)
public PollerMetadata poller(){
    return Pollers
            .fixedDelay(POLLER_FIXED_PERIOD_DELAY)
            .maxMessagesPerPoll(MAX_MESSAGES_PER_POLL)
            .transactional()
            .get();
}

/**
 * The direct channel for the flow.
 *
 * @return MessageChannel
 */
@Bean
public MessageChannel stockIntermediateChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}
/**
 * Get the files from a remote directory. Add a timestamp to the filename
 * and write them to a local temporary folder.
 *
 * @return IntegrationFlow
 */

@Bean
public PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore store() {
    PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore store = new PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore();
    return store;
}
   public IntegrationFlow fileInboundFlowFromFTPServer(Branch myBranch) throws IOException {

    final FtpInboundChannelAdapterSpec sourceSpecFtp = Ftp.inboundAdapter(createNewFtpSessionFactory(myBranch))
            .preserveTimestamp(true)
          //.patternFilter("*.csv")
            .maxFetchSize(MAX_MESSAGES_PER_POLL)
            .remoteDirectory(myBranch.getFolderPath())
            .regexFilter("FEFOexport"+myBranch.getBranchCode()+".csv")
            .deleteRemoteFiles(true)
            .localDirectory(new File(myBranch.getBranchCode()))
            .temporaryFileSuffix(TEMPORARY_FILE_SUFFIX)


            /*.localFilenameExpression(new FunctionExpression<String>(s -> {
                final int fileTypeSepPos = s.lastIndexOf('.');
                return DateTimeFormatter
                        .ofPattern(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT_OF_FILES)
                        .withZone(ZoneId.of(TIMEZONE_UTC))
                        .format(Instant.now())
                        + "_"
                        + s.substring(0,fileTypeSepPos)
                        + s.substring(fileTypeSepPos);
            }))*/;

    // Poller definition
    final Consumer<SourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec> stockInboundPoller = endpointConfigurer -> endpointConfigurer
            .id("stockInboundPoller")
            .autoStartup(true)
            .poller(poller());

    IntegrationFlow flow = IntegrationFlows
            .from(sourceSpecFtp, stockInboundPoller)

            .transform(File.class, p ->{
                // log step
                LOG1.info("flow=stockInboundFlowFromAFT, message=incoming file: " + p);
                return p;
            })
            .handle(m -> {
                try {
                    this.csvToCSVNoQ.writeCSVfinal("test", myBranch.getBranchCode() + "/final" + myBranch.getBranchCode() + ".csv", myBranch.getBranchCode() + "/FEFOexport" + myBranch.getBranchCode() + ".csv");
                    LOG1.info("Writing final file .csv " + m);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            })
            .get();

    return flow;
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow stockIntermediateStageChannel() {
    IntegrationFlow flow = IntegrationFlows
            .from(CHANNEL_INTERMEDIATE_STAGE)
            .transform(p -> {
                //log step
                LOG1.info("flow=stockIntermediateStageChannel, message=rename file: " + p);

                return p;
            })
            //TODO
            .channel(new NullChannel())
            .get();

    return flow;

}

/*
* Creating the outbound adaptor to send files from local to FTP server
*
* */


public IntegrationFlow localToFtpFlow(Branch myBranch){

         return IntegrationFlows.from(Files.inboundAdapter(new File(myBranch.getBranchCode()))
                    .filter(new ChainFileListFilter<File>()
                            .addFilter(new RegexPatternFileListFilter("final" + myBranch.getBranchCode() +".csv"))
                            .addFilter(new FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(metadataStore(dataSource), "foo"))),//FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter
            e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(10_000)))

            .transform( p ->{
                LOG1.info("Sending file " + p + " to FTP branch " + myBranch.getBranchCode());

                return p;
            })


            .log()
            .handle(Ftp.outboundAdapter(createNewFtpSessionFactory(myBranch),FileExistsMode.REPLACE)
                    .useTemporaryFileName(true)
                    .autoCreateDirectory(false)
                    .remoteDirectory(myBranch.getFolderPath()), e -> e.advice(expressionAdvice()))
                    )
            .get();
}


    @Bean
public Advice expressionAdvice() {
    ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice advice = new ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice();
    //advice.setSuccessChannelName("success.input");
    advice.setOnSuccessExpressionString("payload.delete() + ' was successful'");
    //advice.setFailureChannelName("failure.input");
    advice.setOnFailureExpressionString("payload + ' was bad, with reason: ' + #exception.cause.message");
    advice.setTrapException(true);
    return advice;
}


public DefaultFtpSessionFactory createNewFtpSessionFactory(Branch branch){
    final DefaultFtpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();
    factory.setHost(branch.getHost());
    factory.setUsername(branch.getUsern());
    factory.setPort(branch.getFtpPort());
    factory.setPassword(branch.getPassword());
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentMetadataStore metadataStore(final DataSource dataSource) {
    return new JdbcMetadataStore(dataSource);
}

}
```

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand, but why can't you set the `lastModified` property on `bar.csv` to the `foo.csv`'s value? And "but since the handler methods keeps on reading the foo.csv" - why keep re-processing it if it has not changed?

Comment: The bar.csv is generated from foo.csv first time and it is being sent , then it seems the handler method is rewriting a new bar.csv after few seconds based on the poller from the same foo.csv and repeating, not sure how I can stop that and in all cases I want to archive the foo.csv after being processed , better to archive it on the ftp server so that operations team can view historic data when ever they want...I hope it is more clearer now,please do let me know if you want any further explanation @Gary Russell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK; part of the problem is you are re-fetching the remote file on every poll. However, it's not clear why it is being sent again as a new message because the default `.localFilter` is an `AcceptOnceFileListFilter` so it should be ignored; perhaps debug logging, or running in a debugger will help figure out what's happening there.

You should add an `FtpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` to the `.filter`. That way, you will only re-fetch the file if the timestamp changes on the remote server.

Further, if you want to handle such situations, the `localFilter` needs a `FileSystemAcceptOnceFileListFilter` so it will pass the file if the timestamp changes.

Comment: Um sounds a good idea to try, just want to note that I'm deleting the remote file from the ftp server after fetching it the first time so isn't it kinda weird that it will fetch it again?shouldn't it do nothing if there is no file on the remote location?thanks@Gary Russell

Comment: Yes; it should do nothing, but if you don't remove the local copy, it should be stopped by the `AcceptOnceFLF`; not sure why it's not; probably best to remove the local foo.csv too.

Comment: Yes, I want to send the foo.csv to a History folder for archiving on the remote server, wanted to see if I need to create a new flow for that or can add it to the outbound flow along side with the bar.csv so sending both back at the same flow...what you think is the better approach? @Gary Russell

Comment: You can use an `ExpressionEvaluatingAdvice` on the outbound adapter to rename the file.

Comment: Alright cool, sounds good...I guest I can add another handle in the localltoftpflow method to handle the foo.csv to the server, then I can delete both. I saw that I can us something that is called chain advice but I only saw it in XML config...is there a place to see how this is do e in DSL? I think this could be used to delete the local files/payloads if not wrong @Gary Russell

Comment: `.handle(... , e -> e.advice(...))`

Comment: I have added the expression advice method and tried deleting the payload as you can see, I also view some examples that we rename the file..etc. the payload in this case is the final output bar.csv and it is being deleted after sending it to ftp, this is fine for me,but I want to send the original file foo.csv that I pulled it from FTP at first place to a history folder on FTP server, is it possible to add it to the the same flow which is localToFtpFlow method, since the payload is the bar.csv or I have to create a new method with new flow for this purpose?@Gary Russell

Comment: Don't ask new questions in comments; it doesn't help the community find questions/answers. You can do it in a single flow by adding the original file as a header (e.g. `FileHeaders.ORIGINAL_FILE`), then use the `successChannel` on the advice to invoke a flow that does all the post processing you need. If you need help with that, ask a new question.

Comment: The message sent to the success channel is an `AdviceMessage` with properties `message` and `evalResult`, the result of evaluating the expression.